# iMac can't unzip password protected PC zipped file

Tags: zip

I sent a .zip file to a friend with an iMac but he can't open it. It was created using PKZip on a Windows 7 PC, and it's Password protected. He's pretty technically inept so is there anything he needs to do to be able to access this file please?

Comment: There is no need for a third-party utility, just double-click the file and when it prompts for the password, type it in and click OK.

Comment: He's saying it doesn't, but he's not giving me any error messages or anything. I've got ZIP set to AES256 bit encryption and Strong Passphrase. I'm going to try "watering it down" to see if that's what is causing the problem. The password also had a $ in it so I'll try removing that too.

Answer (score 2):

macOS has built-in support for password protected Zip files, but if he encounters problems have him get [The Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12&at=1001lwpF). It also does other kinds of file types.